# dropdownlist date/week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i'm newbie in ruby on rails... I'm having problem in my dropdown list.. the must show 3 weeks advance than the current week.. for e.g. week 39 .. it should be wekk. 42 but the current week should be automatically selected... week 39.. here's my code..

```
<%= select_tag("stock_movement", options_for_select(StockMovement.order("year DESC, week DESC").limit(20).map { | val | [ "#{ val.year }/#{ val.week }", val.id] }, :selected => @stock_movement)) %>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<% cweek = Date.today.cweek 
   sms =StockMovement.where(week: (cweek..cweek+3)).order("year DESC, week DESC")
   sms_now = sms.last.id
%>
<%= select_tag("stock_movement", options_for_select(sms.map { | val | [ "#{ val.year }/#{ val.week }", val.id] }, :selected => sms_now)) %>
```

- and then consider to move the options initialization to the controller.

If fiddled with it a bit more, and here's another solution using the form.select helper and preselecting the value in the model holding the reference (Seminar in my case) if present, the current week otherwise.

```
<% cweek = Date.today.cweek 
   sms =StockMovement.where(week: (cweek..cweek+3)).order("year DESC, week DESC") 
   sms_selected = @seminar.stock_movement ?   @seminar.stock_movement.id : StockMovement.where(week: cweek).first.id

%>
<%= f.select("stock_movement_id", sms.map { | val | [ "#{ val.year }/#{ val.week }", val.id] },{:selected => sms_selected}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve things like this with JQuery. Datepicker plugin can all you need.